# Does the fanatic badge make sense on a travelers stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I have been trying to get the fanatic badge, but everytime on the road aka travelling, I can start from scratch due to some lack of connectivity.

Shouldn't we have an alternative fanatic badge. A gold medal indicating the ultimate traveler. Now getting the fanaticbadge means you haven't been travelling for more then 100 days, sort of disqualifying you from a travel gold medal

Comment: Saaaaaaame. I've never got the fanatic badge for the same reason.

Comment: I got into the 90s on 3 occasions, then travelled, before finally getting it while in Canada.  It was bittersweet, as it meant I hadn't travelled in a bit :/

Answer (score 5):

Yes it makes sense. Nowadays it is possible to travel and to stay connected to the www. Anyway, the badge does not require to stay connected 24/24. One visit per day suffices.

Comment: I think I managed to get this badge when I was travelling. At least I got one of the badges for participating each day for N days and I hardly missed a day at the beginning because I was actually fanatical that the site finally came into existence after I'd found StackOverflow to be so useful as a programmer.

Answer (score 4):

On the contrary, we should have a new set of badges for using travel.SE from many countries!

- Bronze when you use travel.SE from five countries. ***Explorer***
- Silver when you use it from ten countries. <sup>Name?</sup>
- Gold when you use it from twenty countries. ***Globetrotter***

And for those who travel a lot but don't get the opportunity to go abroad, *if* it's possible to resolve IP addresses to airports:

- Bronze when you use travel.SE from five airports. <sup>Name?</sup>
- Silver when you use it from ten airports. <sup>Name?</sup>
- Gold when you use it from twenty airports. ***Frequent Flyer***

-- I can't think up names for all six though (-:

Comment: Gold badge for Globetrotter: **VPN Expert**.

Comment: We couldn't do this when the site started, BEFORE I travelled from London to Mongolia? Dammit ;)

Comment: Because I am so evil that I waited for you to finish before unleashing my idea d-:

Comment: I sound say boy scout for bronze and explorer for silver

Comment: Explorer / Globetrotter / Nomad? Frequent flyer / Jetsetter / Pilot?

Comment: Sorry, not Pilot - *Aeronaut*

Comment: Do you think we should seriously propose this feature on meta.SO?